# Out of stock wording

Tags: magento2, out-of-stock

we have a website that is running on Magento 2. This site has been enabled to show out of stock products. Below each out of stock product it displays 'out of stock' how can i change the wording of this to say 'currently out of stock'.

Thanks

Comment: Check my answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/307425/59677

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change this text-only for product details page and for that section which you mentioned then you need to copy the following file to your theme:

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/default.phtml
```

Your theme file location will be like below:

```
app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Theme]/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/type/default.phtml
```

And update the text.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

If my answer helped you, you can accept the answer so it can help others also.

Comment: vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/default.phtml i cannot find this anywhere?

Comment: Please check this link: https://prnt.sc/rjfh69

Comment: @alishagwcd Have you checked shared link?

Comment: @alishagwcd If my answer helped you, you can accept the answer so it can help others also.

Answer (score 0):

Create the `en_US.csv` file if not exist in

> **app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Theme]/i18n/**

And add the below content.

```
"Out of stock","Currently out of stock"
```

Clear the cache and check. This works for me, Check the below screenshots:

**Product Page:**

[image]

**Category Page:**

[image]

Comment: this method hasn't worked for me

Comment: Have you created the same file as in my post?

Comment: You have to create the file in your active theme.

Comment: the file was already there in my theme - i am using porto

Comment: Please check if there is already added the Out of stock text you just replace the translated word and if not you have to add at end of the file.

Comment: I have done this and it still hasn't worked

Comment: Okay, have you cleared the cache after changes? you can also try with the inline translate. This will default magento tool. You have to enable the translate inline from admin->store->configuration->advanced->Developer. Check this guide . https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/system/translate-inline.html

Comment: Let me know if this will still not work for you.

Comment: There is no developer option for me. All I have is admin and systems

Comment: Its because of your Magento in production mode.